# input:focus is not working

Tags: css, input

i tried to google style input box . but i stucked at input:focus. 
code is below 
http://jsfiddle.net/GmgUZ/

```
  input:hover{
    border-bottom-color: #B9B9B9;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-left-color-ltr-source: physical;
    border-left-color-rtl-source: physical;
    border-left-color-value: #B9B9B9;
    border-left-style-ltr-source: physical;
    border-left-style-rtl-source: physical;
    border-left-style-value: solid;
    border-left-width-ltr-source: physical;
    border-left-width-rtl-source: physical;
    border-left-width-value: 1px;
    border-right-color-ltr-source: physical;
    border-right-color-rtl-source: physical;
    border-right-color-value: #B9B9B9;
    border-right-style-ltr-source: physical;
    border-right-style-rtl-source: physical;
    border-right-style-value: solid;
    border-right-width-ltr-source: physical;
    border-right-width-rtl-source: physical;
    border-right-width-value: 1px;
    border-top-color: #A0A0A0;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    }

  input[type="text"]:focus {
  border:1px solid #4D90FE;
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) inset;
  -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) inset;
  box-shadow:0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) inset;

    }
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your fiddle works for me... make sure you're testing in the right browsers.

Comment: is it showing blue line border ...when focused at input

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `input#gText:focus`  instead of `input[type="text"]:focus` and add `outline: none;`

> input#gText:focus {
>   border:1px solid #4D90FE;
>   -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) inset;
>   -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) inset;
>        box-shadow:0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) inset;
>       outline: none;
>       }

demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/GmgUZ/1/

Answer (score 2):

You have a [CSS Specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) problem, what does this means? It means that you have some rule styling that wins over your "input[type="text"] selector, if you really need your selector to win you will need to specify that this styles are more important than the others with the keyword "!important" at the end of each style, try it:

```
input[type="text"]:focus {
    border:1px solid #4D90FE !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) inset !important;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) inset !important;
    box-shadow:0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) inset !important;
    outline: none !important;
}
```

This is not a hack is in the css specification, but if you left this style like that you will regret one day, because you don't have a good specificity, and any rule that you try to apply to this element for example this rule will win over a rule with the id of the element, for example "#my_input_type_text" or class selector ".my-input-text"